# Define which type select union mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 FROM table1 WHERE column2 = :value 
UNION SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 FROM table2 WHERE column2 = :value
```

So I have this query and here's my php:

```
<?php
if(isset($this->info)){
    foreach ($this->info as $infor){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= $infor->column1 ?></td>
    <td><?= $infor->method ?></td>
    <td><?= $infor = ($infor->column3 == 1) ? 'Completed' : 'Incompleted'; ?></td>
    <td><?= $infor->column4 ?></td>
    <td>$<?= number_format($infor->amount, 2, '.', ''); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

Now as you see `<td><?= $infor->method ?></td>`

I would like to show here If it is from table1 or table2, how would I do that?

Comment: If you use union  you can't  know if the row is coming from table1 or table 2 .. and if you add a column for the table the same value are not resolved  in one rows .. so ... try explain better your need

Comment: If union is impossible for this, what would the other way be?

Comment: two distinct select  so you have separated result and you can decide  when  palce the proper value for table

Comment: The union is not impossible, but unions have terrible performance in my experience so I suggest you just run 2 queries.

Comment: If you must use a union then try `SELECT 'TABLE1', column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 = :value UNION SELECT 'TABLE2', column1 FROM table2 WHERE column1 = :value`

Comment: @bassxzero Works, thanks. Post as an answer, and i will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bassxzero's answer will work if you really are looking for all results from Table1 and Table2 regardless of if all columns(1,2,3...) are the same between the table as adding adding the table values into its column list makes them unique.  though you should use UNION ALL not UNION in that case because that is what you are doing.

If there can be exact duplicates of values for columns(1,2,3...) between Table1 and Table2 but you only want to display them as 1 row then you could use a pattern like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN SUM(FromTable) > 2 THEN 'Both Tables'
       WHEN SUM(FromTable) = 2 THEN 'Table2'
       ELSE 'Table1'
    END as FromTable
    ,column1, column2, ...
FROM
    (
       SELECT 1 as FromTable, column1, column2, ...
       FROM
          Table1
       WHERE
          column2 = :value

       UNION ALL

       SELECT 2, column1, column2, ...
       FROM
          Table2
       WHERE
          column2 = :value
    ) t
GROUP BY
    column1, column2, ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, in my experence unions have terrible performance so I suggest you just run two queries.

You can use the query below and filter based on the first columns value.

```
SELECT 'TABLE1', column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 = :value UNION SELECT 'TABLE2', column1 FROM table2 WHERE column1 = :value
```

Comment: The only performance difference between unions and separate queries is from elimination of duplicates. If you know there are no duplicates, use `UNION ALL`. That's clearly the case when you add the table name as an extra column.